# MOUSE_MOVE Event not working with Timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, actionscript

I have a [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html), and when the time expires it goes to another scene.  When you move the mouse, `Timer` gets reset. However, when time expires (and it goes to the other scene) and I go back to the first scene (via clicking the on the stage of the other scene), my timer mouse event no longer works. The time does not get reset, and instead time expires and goes to the other scene again. I put a trace in my `MOUSE_MOVE` event method so I see what is going on in there, and the time is just not being reset.  Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
//Define, Set and Start Timer

var myTimer:Timer;

myTimer = new Timer(10000, 1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
myTimer.start();

//Mouse Move Events, Reset Timer when you move the mouse

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoved);
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, mouseMoved);

//Timer Complete Method

function onTimerComplete(event : TimerEvent) : void 
{
    gotoAndStop(1, "Screensaver");
}

//Time Mouse Move Method, Reset Timer when you move the mouse

function mouseMoved(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    myTimer.stop();
    myTimer.reset();
    myTimer.start();
}
```

And here is the click event on my screensaver scene:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopScreensaver);

function stopScreensaver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    screensaver1.visible = false;
    screensaver2.visible = false;
    screensaver3.visible = false;
    screensaver4.visible = false;
    screensaver5.visible = false;
    screensaver6.visible = false;
    screensaver7.visible = false;
    screensaver8.visible = false;
    touchStart.visible = false;
    timer.stop();
    timer.reset();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopScreensaver);
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerListener);
    stage.removeChild(whiteBackground);
    gotoAndStop(1, "Home");
}
```

Comment: Are there 2 timers? I'm asking because you use two names across your scenes: myTimer (in "Home" scene) and timer (in "Screensaver" scene).

Comment: Is there any chance I could get you to share your project (like on Dropbox)?